# Shap values with cross validation - do I implement the shap values on axis 0 or axis 1?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, shap

Could I please ask, my aim is to use shap with cross validation to identify the most important features for my model.

I have this code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import shap
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


#loading and preparing the data
iris = load_breast_cancer()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
columns = iris.feature_names
#if you don't shuffle you wont need to keep track of test_index, but I think 
#it is always good practice to shuffle your data
kf = KFold(n_splits=2,shuffle=True)

list_shap_values = list()
list_test_sets = list()
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    X_train = pd.DataFrame(X_train,columns=columns)
    X_test = pd.DataFrame(X_test,columns=columns)

    #training model
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    #explaining model
    explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(clf)
    shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
    #for each iteration we save the test_set index and the shap_values
    list_shap_values.append(shap_values)
    list_test_sets.append(test_index)


#combining results from all iterations
test_set = list_test_sets[0]
shap_values = np.array(list_shap_values[0])

for i in range(1,len(list_test_sets)):
    test_set = np.concatenate((test_set,list_test_sets[i]),axis=0)
    shap_values = np.concatenate((shap_values,np.array(list_shap_values[i])),axis=1)

#bringing back variable names    
X_test_df = pd.DataFrame(X[test_set],columns=columns)
cols = X_test_df.columns
sv = np.abs(shap_values[1,:,:]).mean(0)

importance_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "column_name": cols,
    "shap_values": sv
})

#expected result
importance_df.sort_values("shap_values", ascending=False)

print(importance_df)
```

Could I please ask, have I implemented this correctly? Specifically, is this line correct?

```
    test_set = np.concatenate((test_set,list_test_sets[i]),axis=0)
    shap_values = np.concatenate((shap_values,np.array(list_shap_values[i])),axis=1)
```

I saw this in sample code [here](https://lucasramos-34338.medium.com/visualizing-variable-importance-using-shap-and-cross-validation-bd5075e9063a), but I don't understand why I would use axis 0 for the test_set and axis 1 for the shap values. I had asked a question about a bug I had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72599807/how-to-extract-the-most-important-features-from-a-ml-model-using-shap-why-are/72600741?noredirect=1#comment128352183_72600741), and it came up in the comments, but I don't clearly understand the suggeestion in terms of how to code this correctly.

Comment: This seems right to me though absolutely inefficient. Axis 0 for index just concatenates indices along the single axis. Axis 1 for shap values is the same as 0 for index. You end up with 569 for indices, and same 569 for number of datapoints, but this time for axis 1, because axis 0 is already occupied by classes

Comment: Thank you so much, is it possible for you to demonstrate a more efficient way?

Comment: (but don't worry if you can't, thank you for the help, it runs which is the main thing, I was just asking out of curiosity because it's my first time using shap so I'm trying to understand it so having examples of the best/most efficient ways to use it in my context by basing it on this code would be useful). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import shap
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


#loading and preparing the data
iris = load_breast_cancer()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
columns = iris.feature_names
#if you don't shuffle you wont need to keep track of test_index, but I think 
#it is always good practice to shuffle your data
kf = KFold(n_splits=2,shuffle=True)

list_shap_values = list()
list_test_sets = list()
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    X_train = pd.DataFrame(X_train,columns=columns)
    X_test = pd.DataFrame(X_test,columns=columns)

    #training model
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    #explaining model
    explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(clf)
    shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
    #for each iteration we save the test_set index and the shap_values
    list_shap_values.append(shap_values)


# flatten list of lists, pick the sv for 1 class, stack the result
shap_values = np.vstack([sv[1] for sv in list_shap_values])
sv = np.abs(shap_values).mean(0)  # <-- error corrected    
importance_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "column_name": columns,
    "shap_values": sv
})
```